# Pull an svn repo into one folder in my git-controlled application

Tags: svn, git

I have an application with which i manage the source control with git.  One of the folders is just a copy of the contents of another folder that is in outside the app, in an svn-controlled repo.  To be specific:

this folder:

```
<app root>/public/assets/players/millionaire
```

Just needs to use the contents of an svn repo with the url:

```
http://<my_domain>/charanga/elearning%20players/millionaire_DEPLOY
```

Currently my workflow is

- get notified that the svn repo has been updated
- go to the svn folder and do "svn update"
- rsync the contents of the svn folder (minus the .svn folders) into the relevant app folder
- "git status" to see the changes and "git commit" to commit them in.

This is kind of clumsy though.  What are my options for incorporating the svn folder automatically?  Can i avoid having all of the .svn folders in my git-controlled codebase?  (There's no rational reason for this, i'd just like to keep it as clean as possible)

grateful for any advice - max

Comment: svn export <URL> should simply write all remote files to the local folder, but I guess it would download everything, not only the changed stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your workflow can be achieved using [CommitMonitor](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/CommitMonitor.html): The tool periodically checks a SVN repo and (according to image 2 in the screenshots), it lets you specify a script that shall be executed when new revisions are detected:

[image]

Content of the script could be (in bash):

```
#!/bin/bash
# define variables
SVN_REPO="http://<my_domain>/charanga/elearning%20players/millionaire_DEPLOY"
GIT_REPO="$APP_ROOT/public/assets/players/millionaire"
# fetch latest svn revision
svn export --force $SVN_REPO $GIT_REPO # force because the files already exist
cd $GIT_REPO
# commit the changes to git
git commit -a -m "pulled in from SVN"
```

This way, you don't need to have a local WC of the SVN repo at all...